# How to extract a specific field from a text dataset?

Tags: r

my data

```
dfx=structure(list(V1 = c("(Description and Operation, 100-00 General Information) <a data-searchnum=G2107576  data-procuid=G1620638>Acceleration Control - Overview", 
                      "(Description and Operation, 310-02 Acceleration Control) <a data-searchnum=G2232632  data-procuid=G2210282>Acceleration Control - System Operation and Component Description", 
                      "(Description and Operation, 310-02 Acceleration Control) <a data-searchnum=G2232633  data-procuid=G2210283>Acceleration Control", 
                      "(Diagnosis and Testing, 310-02 Acceleration Control) <a data-searchnum=G2118147  data-procuid=G2118148>Accelerator Pedal ")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                      -4L))
```

I require to extract the `data-searchnum` and store it in a new df

```
G2107576
G2232632
G2232633
G2118147
G2110035
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str_extract` with a capture group (`(...)`) after the `data-searchnum=` substring

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(dfx$V1, 'data-searchnum=(\\S+)', group = 1)
[1] "G2107576" "G2232632" "G2232633" "G2118147"
```

Or str_replace to capture the non-whitespace characters after the `data-searchnum=` and replace with backreference (`\\1`)

```
 str_replace(dfx$V1, ".*data-searchnum=(\\S+)\\s+.*", "\\1")
[1] "G2107576" "G2232632" "G2232633" "G2118147"
```

---

If we are creating a new data

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- dfx %>%
       mutate(V1 = str_extract(V1, 'data-searchnum=(\\S+)', group = 1))
> df2
        V1
1 G2107576
2 G2232632
3 G2232633
4 G2118147
```

---

Or in `base R`, use the same methodology as in `str_replace`

```
sub(".*data-searchnum=(\\S+)\\s+.*", "\\1", dfx$V1)
[1] "G2107576" "G2232632" "G2232633" "G2118147"
```

Comment: @AndresMora I used `packageVersion('stringr')#
[1] ‘1.5.0’`

Comment: I have changed the test df. Please see updated question

Comment: ohh i see. the column! thanks